# UglifyJS does not mangle function names in TypeScript-generated JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, uglifyjs

I have a simple TypeScript class, which I transpile to ES5 and then bundle with webpack 2 and minimize with UgilfyJS3.

I would expect UgilfyJS to also mangle the function name `showGreeting()` (see code below), but in the minified js-file, it is not. Is there any other option I can set to minify the function names or am I doing something worng?
I understand that the variable name is not mangled, but why not the function name?

Here is the original TypeScript file:

```
export class Greeter {
    constructor(greeting: string) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    greeting: string;
    showGreeting() {
        console.log(this.greeting);
    }
}

const myGreeter = new Greeter("hello, world");
myGreeter.greeting = "howdy";
myGreeter.showGreeting();
```

And this is the webpack.config including UglifyJS:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './test.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            mangle: {
                toplevel: true,
                eval: true
            }
        }), 
]
};
```

And the generated output Javascript contains the following lines:

```
[function (e, t, r) {
            "use strict";
            Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
                value: !0
            });
            var n = function () {
                function e(e) {
                    this.greeting = e
                }
                return e.prototype.showGreeting = function () {
                    console.log(this.greeting)
                },
                e
            }
            ();
            t.Greeter = n;
            var o = new n("hello, world");
            o.greeting = "howdy",
            o.showGreeting()
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class members are object properties, and **UglifyJS** doesn't mangle property names. Here is [an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16335097/3786294).

The **Closure compiler** from Google can do the job. But it is hard to use, [with limitations](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations#restrictions-for-advanced_optimizations).

Comment: An "ugly" alternative is to prefix anything which is a class member with an underscore (variables, functions) and configure Uglify to mangle all properties starting with "_" - mangleProperties: { regex: /^_/ }